# Django url not found upon submitting form

Tags: python, django, forms

My apologies if the question is stupid, I am a newbie to this. I am creating a django web application. I have created a form inside it. When I submit the form, it says 'url' not found even though the same URL loads fine for the first time when opening the form. This is whats confusing me. Here is my code:

```
#forms.py
class Recipe_ruleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe_rule
        fields = ('content',)

#urls.py

    url(r"^create_recipe_rule/(?P<recipe_pk>[0-9]+)/$",views.create_recipe_rule, name="create_recipe_rule"),

#views.py
def create_recipe_rule(request, recipe_pk):
    form = Knowledgebase_ruleForm
    selected_recipe = Recipe.objects.get(pk = recipe_pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
           form = Recipe_ruleForm(request.POST)
           if form.is_valid():
               #current_user = request.user
               data = form.cleaned_data
               recipe_rule_data=Recipe_rule.objects.create(recipe=selected_recipe, content=data['content'])
               recipe_rule_data.save()
               recipe_rule = Recipe_rule.objects.get(pk = recipe_rule_data.pk)
               recipe=selected_recipe
               recipe = Recipe.objects.get(pk = recipe.pk)
               return redirect('recipe_detail', pk=recipe.pk)
           else:
               messages.error(request, "Error")
    return render(request, 'create_recipe_rule.html' , {'form': form})
```

Here is the error when I submit the form:

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  POST Request
>   URL:  http://[ip_adress]:[port]/create_recipe_rule/

**UPDATE:**

Here is my template:

```
{% extends "account/base.html" %}

{% load i18n %}
{% load bootstrap %}

{% block body_class %}applications{% endblock %}

{% block head_title %}{% trans "Create recipe" %}{% endblock %}

{% block body %}




<form action="/create_recipe_rule/" method="post">
{% csrf_token  %}




<div class="form-group">
<label for="{{ form.content.label }}">{{ form.content.label }}:</label>
<textarea type="{{ form.content.type }}" name="{{ form.content.name }}" max_length="500" class="form-control" id="{{ form.content.id }}"></textarea>
</div>




     <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Your regex will match urls like `/create_recipe_rule/5/`, but the url from your error message `/create_recipe_rule/` is missing the `recipe_pk` argument. Please show your template, it might give a hint what the problem is.

Comment: What's your form's action attribute set to? The error message is saying that http://[ip_adress]:[port]/create_recipe_rule/ cannot be found and that is because it does not have a primary key value appended at the end. Your URL declaration in your urls.py requires a pk value at the end.

Comment: I have posted my template here, please advise me on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `action="/create_recipe_rule/"`, which is missing the recipe id.

One option is to simply remove the action from the form, then your browser will submit the request to the current url.

```
<form method="post">
```

If you do want to include the form action, then first you need to update your view so that it includes the recipe id in the template context.

```
return render(request, 'create_recipe_rule.html' , {'form': form, recipe_id: recipe_id })
```

Then you can update the form action to include the recipe id.

```
action="/create_recipe_rule/{{ recipe_id }}"
```

It's good practice to use the `{% url %}` tag, so that you are not hardcoding urls in the template:

```
action="{% url 'create_recipe_rule' recipe_id %}"
```

Comment: this fixed it! Thanks a lot! @Alasdair